# Cannot ⌘+V paste into Finder Go to Folder field

Tags: finder, shortcut, bug, copy-paste

[image: Screenshot of Finder Go to Folder field]

When using Finder Go to Folder [⌘+Shift+G], the field will not accept ⌘+V pasted text. I've tested this on 2 Macs (Monterey) with the same result.

The workaround is to paste from the right-click menu, but this defeats the purpose of using the time-saving Go shortcut.

Anyone else experiencing this?

More info:

- Issue occurs on macOS Monterey 12.4
- Have tested on 3x Macs now; M1 Mac mini and 2x M1 MacBook Pro (mine and a colleague's)

Comment: No issues here. Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I've tried rebooting. Have also tested this on multiple Macs, my own and others. It does not appear to be a local issue. Would like to confirm which other Monterey 12.4 users (if not more) are experiencing.

Comment: Are you copying from anywhere specific? Try plaintext from textedit to be sure.